# I.Y.H.O, what phase of software development takes the most time (besides maintenance)?

Tags: time

In your experience, what phase of software development takes the most time? That is besides maintenance, of course. And which phase takes the second most time? Which methodology do you use?

Comment: ...the fixing/workarounds for Internet Explorer bugs part takes most of my time

Answer (score 2):

The final 20% always takes the longest - roughly 80% of the total time of the project.

I don't think there is any methodology that will change this. As a project begins to take its final form and is demoed its always easier for clients to think of new ideas and improvements. I think the best way to handle it is to keep open communication with the client, be open to change suggestions, but make sure they are aware that their changes will increase the development cost.